# no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list c++ - Create Modeless dialog

Tags: c++, mfc, modeless-dialog

I'm trying to create a modeless dialog from resource by using Create() and ShowWindow() function.
But it end up getting error "no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list c++"
Here is my Appication command.cpp

```
void
CSurveyApp::OnAskAI()
{
    //MessageBox()
    /*dlg_AskAI dlg_AskAI;
    dlg_AskAI.DoModal();*/
    dlg_AskAI m_dialog;
    if (!m_dialog) {
        m_dialog.Create(IDD_ASKAI, this);
        m_dialog.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    }
    
    
}
```

Here is dialog.h file

```
#pragma once
#include "afxdialogex.h"


// dlg_AskAI dialog

class dlg_AskAI : public CDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(dlg_AskAI)

public:
    dlg_AskAI(CWnd* pParent = nullptr);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~dlg_AskAI();

// Dialog Data
#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum { IDD = IDD_ASKAI };
#endif

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP();
public:
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton2();
    afx_msg void OnEnChangeEdit3();
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton3();
    afx_msg void OnEnChangeEdit4();
    afx_msg void OnClose();
private:
    CString m_message;

};
```

Here is dialog.cpp file

```
// dlg_AskAI.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "dlg_AskAI.h"


// dlg_AskAI dialog

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(dlg_AskAI, CDialog)

dlg_AskAI::dlg_AskAI(CWnd* pParent /*=nullptr*/)
    : CDialog(IDD_ASKAI, pParent)
    , m_message(_T(""))
{

}
CString m_message;
dlg_AskAI::~dlg_AskAI()
{
}

void dlg_AskAI::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT3, m_message);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(dlg_AskAI, CDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON2, &dlg_AskAI::OnBnClickedButton2)
    ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_EDIT3, &dlg_AskAI::OnEnChangeEdit3)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON3, &dlg_AskAI::OnBnClickedButton3)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_EDIT4, &dlg_AskAI::OnEnChangeEdit4)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


void dlg_AskAI::OnClose()
{
    DestroyWindow();
}
//Contact Us
void dlg_AskAI::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
}


void dlg_AskAI::OnEnChangeEdit3()
{
    // TODO:  If this is a RICHEDIT control, the control will not
    // send this notification unless you override the CDialog::OnInitDialog()
    // function and call CRichEditCtrl().SetEventMask()
    // with the ENM_CHANGE flag ORed into the mask.

    // TODO:  Add your control notification handler code here

    
}

//Send Button
void dlg_AskAI::OnBnClickedButton3()
{
    
}


void dlg_AskAI::OnEnChangeEdit4()
{
  
}
```

it end up with this error

```
no instance of overloaded function "dlg_AskAI::Create" matches the argument list
```

First time asking, please go easy on me. Note that, I have very minimal experience on C++ please help with heart T.T

Comment: second argument should be `CWnd*` not `CApp*`, you should pass nullptr if it isn't expecting a parent window.

Comment: or just omit the second argument completely, it defaults to nullptr.

Comment: But, in that case when I build solution,it build successfully but it doesn't work for some reason(cannot open dialog)

Comment: *"it end up with this error"* - That's not the full error diagnostic. The compiler explained what it tried and how it failed. Please include the full error message.

Comment: no instance of overloaded function "dlg_AskAI::Create" matches the argument list survOPT
 
73       argument types are: (int, CSurveyApp *)
            object type is: dlg_AskAI

Comment: *"error 'no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list c++'"* -- Really? The error message from your compiler ends with "c++"?

Comment: Since the real error message mentions `dlg_AskAI::Create`, you can use that to simplify your [mre]. Get rid of everything other than what you need to invoke that function. Don't worry about functionality; there is no functionality from code that does not compile. All you want is code that can be copied and compiled to reproduce the error message. What is needed beyond `void
CSurveyApp::OnAskAI()
{
m_dialog.Create(IDD_ASKAI, this);
}` and `class dlg_AskAI : public CDialog
{};`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

second argument of [CDialog::Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class?view=msvc-170#create) should be `CWnd*` not `CApp*`, you should leave the second argument empty which defaults it to null.

you have a problem with the lifetime of the dialog, modeless dialogs (unlike modal ones) cannot be created on the stack. (because 1. they outlast the stack and 2. they should `delete` themselves when they are closed).

to fix this, you need to

1. have a member pointer to the window in your `CApp` object. (optional)
2. allocate the dialog with `new`, and store it in that member.
3. follow MSDN documentation on modelss dialogs cleanup in the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class?view=msvc-170#remarks)

> When you implement a modeless dialog box, **always override the OnCancel
> member function and call DestroyWindow from within it**. Don't call the
> base class CDialog::OnCancel, because it calls EndDialog, which will
> make the dialog box invisible but will not destroy it. **You should also
> override PostNcDestroy for modeless dialog boxes in order to delete
> this**, since **modeless dialog boxes are usually allocated with new**.
> Modal dialog boxes are usually constructed on the frame and do not
> need PostNcDestroy cleanup.

Comment: Solved, thanks for the guidance tho. I wasn't fully understand the documentation so I give it a go up here and turned out I should read it carefully. But thanks for the big help anw